# function inside if statement executing multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a container element that is being loaded multiple times to show variable content on a click event through an Ajax request and upon ajax Complete i have some functions being called including a function (A) inside an if statement.

My problem is when function (A) finally gets called, it gets called multiple times depending on how many times the container had been loaded before the if statement is true.

Here is simple version of my code:

```
$(".button").on("click", function(){
  loadContainer();
});

var loadContainer = function(){
  $(".container").load(url, function(){
    var x = $(".x");
    if(x.length>0){
      A();
    };
  });
};
```

`x` is an element `$(".x")` that will be loaded in the container and the function (A) should only be called when that element gets loaded. i.e. `$(".x").length>0`

if (x.length>0) is true after say 3 times of loading the container then function (A) will be called 3 times then.

is there a way around this or a way to make sure function (A) gets called only once??

Edit:
My full code:

```
    ajaxBtn.on("click", function(e) {

        loadContainer(url, curtain, mainContainer, body, links);
   });
var loadContainer = function(url, curtain, maincontainer, body, links) {

        $(".main-container").load(url + " .main-container  > *", function() {
            $("#logo").css({
                "z-index": "400"
            });

            mainFun();
            curtain.removeClass("full");
            links.removeClass("here");
            body.removeClass("no-scroll");
            clearInterval(timer);
            getFlexIndex();
            position = 0;

            if (vidContainer.length > 0) {
                youTubeLazyLoad();
            }
        });
};
```

please assume that all the variables are already defined.

Comment: take `A()` out of the loop. or `$(document).one('load', A)`

Comment: What is `x`? `A` will be called probably for each `.container` depending of course on the value of the ANONYMOUS `x`.

Comment: `x` is an element `$(".x")` that will be loaded in the container and the function (A) should only be called when that element gets loaded. i.e. `$(".x").length>0`

Comment: Your example is extremely vague, with variables that don't mean anything (`A`, `x`), and you haven't shown us where the `x` variable gets modified at all. Please provide us a more complete example.

Comment: why not just put a counter?

Comment: I think you have something else in your code which are not sharing with us. This code is working fine on my machine and function `A()` is firing one time on my machine...

Comment: maybe the first two payload of `.load` didn't contain any of `".x"` elements.

Comment: @EhsanT i commented out the rest of my code and the problem still exists. 

@ibrahim mahrir yes the first 2 `.load` event don't contain any `".x"`, hence the IF statement to call the function only when `".x"` exists.

Comment: @Roljhon can you please explain what do you mean and how the counter would help??

Comment: My bet is you are calling the button click listener more than once. Try changing `$(".button").on("click"...` to `$(".button").off('click').on("click"...` to verify. Not enough shown for us to troubleshoot

Comment: Since I can not reproduce the problem with my minified version on my machine, then the problem is from your code and it's not a general issue. This code you have in your question, does not reproduce the issue you are mentioning. unless you have something else in your code that we do not have here in your question

Comment: @charlietfl i'm quite sure that this is not the case because i have `console.log()` for the click event and it only fires once.

Comment: Well without a [mcve] is impossible for us to help more without a lot of guessing

Comment: is there more than one  `container` element? If so would be called for each

Comment: @charlietfl i'll attach my full code to show that is the same as the one i've provided just with more code for other elements. and there is only one `container`

Comment: does `url` contain the same script? Did you try using `off()`?

Comment: Maybe there are elements with `container` class in the content of `url`?

Comment: @charlietfl & @EhsanT i've attached my full code. no `url` doesn't have class `container` inside because i load the content of the class `container` from that `url`.

Comment: Nothing shown would cause symptoms mentioned. Problem is elsewhere. Possibly loading same script more than once?

Comment: Sorry pal, it seems that we can not find your problem. But one question, You said 3 times click on the button, and then if the `.x` exists will cause `A()` function fire 3 times. is it always 3 times or if you for example click on the button 7 times and then on the 8 time `.x` exist, then the function will fire 8 times?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your time and effort i'll keep trying to figure out the problem and i'll post back if i find out the cause of the problem. and sorry if i wasted any of your time.

Comment: Not a waste , that's what this site is all about....trying to help. Unfortunately we can't see all of the code and play with it in browser dev tools

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are adding the same button click listener numerous times

You should look into how this occurs as there is not enough shown for us to know why. Is it embedded inside another event handler perhaps? Or in a function that gets called numerous times?

A workaround is to remove the click listener before adding a new one

Change

```
$(".button").on("click"...
```

to

```
$(".button").off('click').on("click"...
```

Comment: This will not solve the problem I guess. Because he already check for `$(".x").length > 0` more calls would be pointless if there is at least `".x"` elements.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir length of `$(".x")` is irrelevant if one exists and event listener is applied more than once or function `loadContainer` is called more than once or `$(".container").length>1`

Comment: But even if the function `loadContainer` is called more than once, the check `$(".x").length > 0` will be true thus `A` will never be called. The problem is probably something else (hidden in that mysterious code).

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir that logic doesn't make sense